# Creating Html Helper Method - MVC Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am learning MVC from Stephen Walther tutorials on MSDN website. He suggests that we can create Html Helper method.

Say Example

```
using System;
namespace MvcApplication1.Helpers
{
          public class LabelHelper
          {
               public static string Label(string target, string text)
               {
                    return String.Format("<label for='{0}'>{1}</label>",
                    target, text);
               }
          }
}
```

My Question under which folder do i need to create these class?

View folder or controller folder? or can i place it in App_Code folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a subfolder Extensions in which define helper methods:

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
        public static string MyLabel(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string target, string text)
        {
            var builder = new TagBuilder("label");
            builder.Attributes.Add("for", target);
            builder.SetInnerText(text);
            return builder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

In your view you need to reference the namespace and use the extension method:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="SomeNamespace" %>

<%= Html.MyLabel("abc", "some text") %>
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be returning an IHtmlString?

Answer (score 1):

You can place it wherever you like. The important thing is that it make sense to you (and everyone working on the project). Personally I keep my helpers at this path: `/App/Extensions/`.

Answer (score 0):

Place it in the app code. However, ASP.NET MVC 2 already has the `Label` functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could put in the Models folder, or App_Code (not sure what kinds of support is in MVC for that); it would be best to have in a separate library.  Also, html helper extensions are extension methods that must start with the this HtmlHelper html parameter like:

```
public static class LabelHelper 
         { 
               public static string Label(this HtmlHelper html, string target, string text) 
               { 
                    return String.Format("<label for='{0}'>{1}</label>", 
                    target, text); 
               } 
          }
```

**EDIT:** You can reference this within the namespace by adding it to the:

```
<pages>
   <namespaces>
```

Element within the configuration file too, that way you define the namespace once, and it's referenced everywhere.

Comment: Correct. If it doesn't start with this HtmlHelper html, then it is not the extension and you have to call it like LabelHelper.Label instead of Html.Label