# Can I display multiselect list items as onordered list using Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.1, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I was wondering if this is possible with razor syntax (I have found that there are other ways that utilize jquery). Please point me in the right direction if you know one. I am working on a MVC 5 project.
Thanks.

Comment: A custom helper can be used to display whatever html you want but if you want some behavior e.g. to be able to select something from the list and do something with it then you going to need javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible by creating custom html helper methods. Refer this little [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432551/creating-html-helper-method-mvc-framework) which would be helpful.

[Video version of tutorial](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/AnthonyC/Extending-ASPNET-MVC-with-Custom-HTML-Helpers)

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely try this.