# How to build HTML from Code in C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, dom

I need to create an HtmlHelper in my MVC application which renders out some nested and fairly complex UL/LI (tree-like) structures. The `HtmlTextWriter` and `XmlTestWriter` classes provide means to construct proper HTML, but they are forward-only thus making my job pretty difficult, since after you rendered a tag you don't have a reference to "parent" tag.

`XDocument` and `XElement` classes were the next candidates I looked at, but they have been created for XML and not for HTML, which might result in *no-so-valid* HTML (self-closing tags etc.).

How would I go about this?

[This alleged duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432551) is not really a duplicate and doesn't answer my question at all. It is about building an HTML-Helper rendering a single Html-Tag. This is not what I am after. I'd like to know how to build an entire DOM in C# code.

Comment: Recommend you explore the [MVC source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) - look at the System.Web.MVC.Html namespace. An example of a helper to create a hierarchical tree structure is shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27146524/how-to-render-singly-linked-list-in-mvc-view-page/27147744#27147744). Generally you use the `TagBuilder` class to construct html elements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Html Helper Method - MVC Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432551/creating-html-helper-method-mvc-framework)

Answer (score 1):

If I were to go about doing this, I'd do it in a way such as this (simplified):

**Item Class**

```
    public class HtmlListItem 
    {
         public string Content { get; set; }
         public object HtmlAttributes { get; set; }
    }
```

**Html Helper**

```
    public HtmlString RenderList(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, IEnumerable<HtmlListItem> list, object uListHtmlAttributes)
        {
            TagBuilder ul = new Tagbuilder("ul");
            IDictionary<string, object> uListAttributes = new RouteValueDictionary(uListHtmlAttributes);
            ul.MergeAttributes(uListAttributes);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.Append(ul.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag) + Environment.NewLine);

            foreach (var item in list) 
            {
                TagBuilder hold = new TagBuilder("li");
                IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = new RouteValueDictionary(item.HtmlAttributes);
                hold.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
                hold.InnerHtml = item.Content;
                builder.Append(hold.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal) + Environment.NewLine);
            }

            builder.Append("</ul>" + Environment.NewLine);
            return new HtmlString(builder.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: can you show sample usage, how are data attributes passed in?

Answer (score 0):

I've wanted to do something like this before, and ended up playing around with an object structure that would represent elements, like a server side DOM, that could be manipulated in code before rendering to HTML.

Others have done similar things.  Notable examples are SharpDOM: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667581/SharpDOM-a-new-view-engine-for-ASP-NET-MVC and CityLizard: https://citylizard.codeplex.com/

These days I tend to build a View Model that deals with most of the logic and manipulation of how the view should look then render that instead.

You may also find partial views (called recursively) a useful approach.